# how to use tkinter with sqlite in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

I had issues with delivering tkinter entry to sqlite
My goal is build user interface to collect data and
delete, show, update, I will keep learning.

I think my problem in

```
def savedata ():
```

I changed what inside brackets

I tried change this also

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO data (fname, sname) VALUES (?,?)', 
(firstname_entry, secondnamename_entry))
conn.commit()
```

.

thank for helping

.

```
import random 
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox 
import sqlite3 

def conacona(): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db') 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stud (firstname TEXT, secondname TEXT)") 
    conn.commit() 
    conn.close() 

#oooooooo 

main_menu = tk.Tk() 

firstname_label = Label(main_menu, text="First name") 
firstname_label.pack() 
secondname_label = Label(main_menu, text="Second name") 
secondname_label.pack() 

# First name get 
firstname_entry = tk.StringVar() 
firstname_entry_entry = Entry(main_menu, textvariable = fn_ent_ent) 
firstname_entry_entry.pack() 

# Second name get 
secondname_entry = tk.StringVar() 
secondname_entry_entry = Entry(main_menu, textvariable = sn_ent_ent) 
secondname_entry_entry.pack() 

def savedata (): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect('stud.db') 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute('INSERT INTO data (fname, sname) VALUES (?,?)', (firstname_entry, secondnamename_entry)) 
    conn.commit() 
    print("OK") 

u_ent_btn = Button(text="Enter",command=savedata()) 
u_ent_btn.pack() 

main_menu.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where are `fn_ent_ent` and `sn_ent_ent` defined?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `fn_ent_ent` with `firstname_entry` and `sn_ent_ent` with `secondname_entry` to refer to the string variables that you created.

There is a typo in the `execute()` statement: it should be `secondname_entry`, not `secondnamename_entry`. Also you need to call `.get()` on the string variables to retrieve the value to be used in the query.

The SQL statement must reference the correct table and column names that were used when the table was created namely `stud` instead of `data`, and`firstname` and `secondname` instead of `fname` and `sname`.

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO stud (firstname, secondname) VALUES (?,?)', (firstname_entry.get(), secondname_entry.get()))
```

Do not call `savedata()` when passing it as the function for the button `command`:

```
u_ent_btn = Button(text="Enter",command=savedata)
```

Finally, you need to call `conacona()` to create the SQLite database before entering the `mainloop()`. And you must use the same file name for the database, so make it one of `stud.db` or `student.db` but not both.

---

Putting all of that together results in this code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

def conacona():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stud (firstname TEXT, secondname TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

#oooooooo 

main_menu = tk.Tk()

firstname_label = Label(main_menu, text="First name")
firstname_label.pack()
secondname_label = Label(main_menu, text="Second name")
secondname_label.pack()

# First name get 
firstname_entry = tk.StringVar()
firstname_entry_entry = Entry(main_menu, textvariable=firstname_entry)
firstname_entry_entry.pack()

# Second name get 
secondname_entry = tk.StringVar()
secondname_entry_entry = Entry(main_menu, textvariable=secondname_entry)
secondname_entry_entry.pack()

def savedata ():
    print(dir(firstname_entry))
    conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO stud (firstname, secondname) VALUES (?,?)', (firstname_entry.get(), secondname_entry.get()))
    conn.commit()
    print("OK")

u_ent_btn = Button(text="Enter",command=savedata)
u_ent_btn.pack()

conacona()
main_menu.mainloop()
```