# Inserting data from an OptionMenu() drop-down menu into an SQLite database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm making a GUI with **drop-down menus** (OptionMenu from tkinter) in python.

I want to insert the data from the drop-down menus into an **SQLite database**, eg there's a drop-down menu for choosing your car and I want to insert the user's car choice into the database along with the date for the entry.

I've been checking out [how to use tkinter with sqlite in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491341/how-to-use-tkinter-with-sqlite-in-python) and [Use OptionMenu in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407476/use-optionmenu-in-python) but I can't get my code to work (see error message).

I'm using Python 3.7.4, Windows 10.

Thanks!

```
from tkinter import * 
import sqlite3 as sq
import datetime

# Main window
window = Tk()

# Connection to SQLite 
con = sq.connect('Cars.db') 

# Car choice variable and placeholder 
carV = StringVar(window)
carV.set('Choose your car') 

# Car choice dictionary for drop-down menu
carD = {'BMW', 'Volvo', 'Mitsubishi'}

# Car chhoice drop-down menu 
carDDM = OptionMenu(window, carV, carD)
carDDM.place(x=150,y=150)

# Function for inserting car choice from drop-down menu into SQLite 
def SaveCarChoice():

        c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (sql_date TEXT, sql_carV INTEGER)') 
        date = datetime.date(int(year.get()),int(month.get()), int(day.get())) 
        c.execute('INSERT INTO (sql_date, sql_carV) VALUES (?, ?)', (date, carDDM.get()) 
        con.commit()

# Button for user to activate the function inserting data into SQLite                    
carB = Button(window, text="Enter",command=SaveCarChoice()) 
carB.pack() 

window.mainloop()

# ERROR MESSAGE
  File "<ipython-input-5-7b7f66e12fbf>", line 42
    con.commit()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing one closing `)` in the line before, which is ` c.execute(...`. And this `carDDM.get()` should read `carV.get()` the `variable=` from the `OptionMenu`

Answer (score 0):

You this i have made some changes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3 as sq
import datetime


# Connection to SQLite
con = sq.connect('Cars.db')

# Car choice dictionary for drop-down menu
carD = ['BMW', 'Volvo', 'Mitsubishi']


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width= 500, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

carV = tk.StringVar(root)
carV.set('Choose your car')

carDDM = tk.OptionMenu(canvas, carV, *carD)
carDDM.pack()

# Function for inserting car choice from drop-down menu into SQLite
def SaveCarChoice():
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CAR (sql_date VARCHAR(20), sql_carV VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)')
    today = str(datetime.date.today())
    today = today[8:] + '-' + today[5:7] + '-' + today[:4]
    c.execute('INSERT INTO CAR (sql_date, sql_carV) VALUES (?, ?)', (today, carV.get()))
    con.commit()

# Button for user to activate the function inserting data into SQLite
carB = tk.Button(canvas, text="Enter", command=SaveCarChoice)
carB.pack()

root.mainloop()
```